# How does test_size relate when used in python sklearn for a 10 fold cross validation

Tags: python-3.x, training-data, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to implement a ML algorithm in which I would like to use a 10 fold cross validation process but I would just like to get confirmation if my procedure is correct.

I am doing a binary classification and have about 50 samples of each class in each of the 10 folders that I created, called `fold 1`, `fold 2`, and so on.

My `sklearn` command is:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, yy, test_size=0.3, random_state=1000)
```

Am I totally wrong here and this procedure is actually just doing a 30% test and 70% train process?  For the 10 fold cross validation, I should be using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I totally wrong here and this procedure is actually just doing a 30% test and 70% train process?

Yes, setting `test_size=0.3` gives you a 30% test size and a 70% train size. We know this from [reading the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

> **test_size float or int, default=None**
>
> If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split

If you're repeating this 10 times with different `random_state`, then there will be some repeated elements in the test set among the 10 repetitions. The purpose of *k*-fold cross-validation is to create *k* **disjoint** sets, and each set used in turn as a holdout. Your procedure is not a cross-validation, because the sets you've produced by this procedure will never be disjoint (you can prove this with the pigeonhole principle).

> `kf = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)`

This isn't a 10-fold CV because `n_splits=2`. We know this from [reading the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html). The argument `n_splits` should be the number of folds. You've said you want 10 splits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The correct method then for a 10-fold will be `kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)`?

Comment: Basically. `shuffle=False` might or might not be important, depending on your goals and whether or not your data is already shuffled; similarly, `random_state=None`.